# Exception while searching

Tags: search, search-results, alternate-access-mapping, https

we have configured a Search Service Application for our SharePoint farm. we have alternate access making configured. The search crawl is working after adding host entry.

However, when we search for content through default SharePoint search we get error.

[image]

Checking ULS logs got this message.

> Original error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: String
>    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>    at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestServiceImpl.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)

However search over specific library is working.

[image]

**Update**

I checked for search on SharePoint server itself. it is working. However, from outside of server (other computers) it is giving this error.

**Have able to nail it down to this 'outside server, search works if request is http. However fails if it is https. That is if application is accessed through http search works whereas if browsed through https it doesn't'**

Kindly let know what we are missing.

Below is AAMs.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You have to check out the aam carefully. It'd be reason I guess,provided you already mentioned search is working fine within server

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for your quick response. Yes i too am doubting the same. I have updated question showing my current AAM urls. Kindly check the same. Network team is redirecting requests to https.

Comment: Try checking these links https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-aams-explained/   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/sharepoint-2013-search-development                                                     https://www.netwoven.com/2016/01/08/sharepoint-2013-alternate-access-mapping-aam-dos-donts/